# Is this correct subject verb agreement?

Tags: verb-agreement

The following is from LSAT 45, LR1, Question 16, Answer choice C:

Most successful writers' **judgments** of their recently completed work **is** unnecessarily harsh and **is** often later revised.

Shouldn't "is" be "are" in both instances?

Comment: The sentence would work best by making *judgment* singular.  But it still feels contrived.  I don't envy you this test prep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, "is" should be "are" in both instances. The subject of the sentence is "judgments", which is plural, which dictates that the verb must also be plural.

See *The Elements of Style*, by William Strunk Jr. and E.B. White, Macmillan, 1979, p. 9:

> **The number of the subject determines the number of the verb.**

Comment: He could be trying to be helpful.  He could be polishing up his answering skills.  He could be taking a break from putting mulch on his garden.

Comment: @aparente001 I appreciate the helping people and giving back aspects of your profile. Nice.

Comment: @RichardKayser I thought it was an obvious mistake also, but because it was on a law school admissions test, I thought there was something I was missing.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: @ChongDogMillionaire My pleasure. I wasn't trying to be insulting with my comment. Prompted by the reaction of another user, I deleted the comment almost immediately, but perhaps not before you saw it. I was puzzled that a user of your reputation would ask such a question. But I get it: it's surprising indeed that the LSAT would contain such obvious errors. Thanks.